# Are there any implementations of the spineless tagless G-machine other than in GHC?

Tags: reference-request, compilers

From Simon Peyton Jones (recent Royal Society member) we read the paper: [Implementing lazy functional languages on stock hardware: the Spineless Tagless G-Machine](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~pbv/aulas/linguagens/peytonjones92implementing.pdf).

Now this paper is part of how they made Haskell a lazy language when they were implementing it, and solved some problems they had at the time.

The only comparable paper seems to be: [Compiling Lazy Functional Programs Based on the Spineless Tagless G-machine for the Java Virtual Machine](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/~khchoi/doc/flops2001.pdf) but there doesn't appear to be an implementation available.

One tangentially related is: [Compiling Haskell to Java](ftp://ftp.cs.yale.edu/pub/TR/tr1204.ps). However in this approach they leave the implementation of the Spineless Tagless G-Machine in GHC and just read the output.

My question is: **Are there any implementations of the spineless tagless G-machine other than in GHC?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this Google search:

```
"spineless tagless g-machine" site:github.com
```

and found 2 repos that (try?) to implement the STG in non-Haskell languages:

PHP: [lechimp-p/php-stg](https://github.com/lechimp-p/php-stg)

RPython ("restricted" subset of Python developed for Pypy): [cgswords/laurens](https://github.com/cgswords/laurens)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good one with nice visualisations:
https://github.com/quchen/stgi

Answer (score 0):

There is an online hosted visual demonstration [here](https://www.theshortlog.com/stg/) with an explanation [here](https://www.theshortlog.com/posts/spineless-tagless-g/).

[Typelead](https://github.com/typelead) was a briefly funded startup that attempted to fork GHC to the JVM (before they ran out of money). [Etalang](https://github.com/typelead/eta) was the result and it contains a [STG](https://gist.github.com/rahulmutt/9bcab8c9b8bc3d99be26c11ae42d2795#stg-execution-model). You can read the code of the STG [here](https://github.com/typelead/eta/blob/97ee2251bbc52294efbf60fa4342ce6f52c0d25c/compiler/Eta/StgSyn/StgSyn.hs).